# Replace array element (integer) in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I have a simple array in React's `state`, consisting of only integers:

```
this.state = {
  myArray: [1,2,3]
}
```

I'm trying to replace a value in an immutable way (value `2` should be replaced by `8`):

```
const valueToReplace = 2
const newValue = 8
const myArray = this.state.myArray
const arrayPosition = myArray.indexOf(valueToReplace)
const newArray = Object.assign([], myArray, {arrayPosition: newValue})

this.setState({myArray: newArray})
```

But my way doesn't change `myArray` in state. I think I'm not using `Object.assign` in the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=example) to copy the array, mutate your copy, then assign it. Since you're creating a new array instead of modifying an existing one, you're still safe from mutation issues.

```
const valueToReplace = 2
const newValue = 8
const newArray = this.state.myArray.slice() // copy
const arrayPosition = newArray.indexOf(valueToReplace)
newArray[arrayPosition] = newValue

this.setState({myArray: newArray})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a clone of an array first and then replace the value:

```
const valueToReplace = 2
const newValue = 8
const myArray = this.state.myArray.slice(0);
const arrayPosition = myArray.indexOf(valueToReplace)
myArray[arrayPosition] = newValue

this.setState({myArray: newArray})
```

The `Object.assign` just clones and object/array into another var and is not changing the value within the array.